# Example of a forgetful functor that is not faithful.

Tags: category-theory

In the [forgetful functor Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgetful_functor)  I read that

> "[Forgetful] Functors that forget the extra sets need not be faithful; distinct morphisms respecting the structure of those extra sets may be indistinguishable on the underlying set."

Can anyone give me an example of  a forgetful functor that is not faithful?

Comment: The Wikipedia article gives examples for all three types of forgetful functors, including functors of the "third kind".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One example is the forgetful functor from Schemes to Sets. Given two fields $k_1, k_2$, there may be many different field homomorphisms $k_1 \to k_2$ which give rise to many different morphisms $\text{Spec }k_2 \to \text{Spec }k_1$. However, the underlying sets of both of these schemes are single points, so there is a unique map between them in the category Sets.

Comment: Remark: There is a faithful functor from schemes (even ringed spaces) to sets, though. It is a good exercise to find it.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg can I have a hint?

Comment: Well, gather all pieces of the structure of a ringed space into one big set.

Answer (score 8):

If $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}$ are categories, then the projection functor $\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ (which "forgets" the second coordinate) is not faithful (unless $\mathcal{D}$ is thin or $\mathcal{C}$ is empty).